# How to convert small icon from notification using NotificationListenerService to byte[]?

Tags: android

I have an app in which I read all the incoming notification from device. I am facing problem in converting small icon into byte[]. How do I do that please help ?

code:-

```
Bundle extras = sbn.getNotification().extras;  
    String title = extras.getString("android.title");  
    String text = extras.getCharSequence("android.text").toString();  
    int id1 = extras.getInt(Notification.EXTRA_SMALL_ICON);
```

Comment: Why do you want to convert to byte array?

Comment: Its app requirement

Answer (score 0):

```
//use : 
    Context remotePackageContext = null; 
    Bitmap bmp = null;
    try {  
        remotePackageContext = getApplicationContext().createPackageContext(pack, 0);  
        Drawable icon = remotePackageContext.getResources().getDrawable(your_id);  
        if(icon !=null) {  
            bmp = ((BitmapDrawable) icon).getBitmap();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }


//now convert this bitmap to byte :

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, baos);
            byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
```

Comment: it is displaying white in color

Comment: i am trying .... remotePackageContext = getApplicationContext().createPackageContext(pack, 0);
            Drawable icon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(remotePackageContext,id1);